# In-terminal / In-console SSH connection manager

Tags: linux, ssh

I need SSH connection manager that works *in terminal*, that is, it's not a complete GUI app or a special terminal where you can define bookmarks or connections.

I want to quickly start SSH connection to one of many configured SSH accounts with minimum effort *from the bash prompt*. I'd start the connection manager and then say browse or start SSH with some key shortcut.

Ideally, the software should be open source (any license but Affero GPL really). Commercial option not excluded.

Comment: As you mention SSH and Bash without any OS: are we right to assume this should be for Linux? Please add the corresponding OS tag if it should be for a specific OS – or mark it cross-platform if that is a requirement. If both fail, [edit] your question and list the options (e.g. "should work on Solaris or AIX" if one of the two is sufficient). Further: should the software come free of monetary costs, or would you have a budget for "commercial solutions"?

Comment: `ssh` has a "connection manager" included. You can configure it in `~.ssh/config` file and then make use of it. Something like this: `select host in $(grep -Po "Host \K.*" ~/.ssh/config); do ssh $host; break; done`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using shell aliases.

For instance if your shell is `bash` you can manage your SSH connections in the `.bashrc` file like this:

```
alias cakes='ssh nicolas@cakes-recipes.fr'
```

If you don't want to type passwords, just set up the standard SSH public key-based authorization.

Once you restart your terminal, you will be able to connect by just typing:

```
cakes
```